# Python 3.x - Simple function that returns another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, currying

I just recently started programming in Python and I've been trying to create a simple function that takes two parameters, a and b, and returns the result of the sum of a and |b|.  I want to return f(a, b) and not just f.  I know that I'm assigning f to be an int in my current code and so it returns "int not callable error" when I run.  So I have to assign f to be a function of some sort.  I'm fairly certain I'm missing something fundamental here, I'm just not sure exactly what.  Thanks for any help!

```
from operator import add, sub

def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    """Return a+abs(b), but without calling abs.

    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, 3)
    5
    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, -3)
    5
    """
    if b < 0:
        f = sub(a, b)
    else:
        f = add(a, b)
    return f(a, b)
```

Comment: `f = sub` and `f = add` should be all you need (you pass the arguments later on when you call `f(a, b)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jean-Fançois's answer is great, but if you're not understanding the fundamentals behind this, you should look into another example that uses lambdas:

```
def returns_function_example():
    return lambda arg1: arg1 + 2

function_returned = returns_function_example()

print(function_returned(1))

# Output = 3
```

Run this in your debugger to see that "function_returned" in indeed a function. You can connect the dots after the "print" function is called.

Comment: So basically the right side of the assignment is computed before assignment occurs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly.. 

Essentially, a function can be thrown around like an object. Lambdas are used across many programming languages and are extremely useful for these cases. You can return lambdas as functions and then call them as if they were a value. If you're still confused, try running this within a debugger, it will make more sense to see the values in real time.

Comment: @fralau does a little extra work for you by printing types out.. You can also try that if you dont want to debug.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = sub(a, b)
```

doesn't create a function it computes the result, so when you're calling `f(a, b)` you're calling an integer.

To fix it, assign the function in-line with a ternary to select which function to create depending on the sign of `b`

```
f = sub if b < 0 else add
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was just confused on how to get around computing the value of add and sub.  very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first-class citizens in Pythonland, so that you can manipulate them as any other object.

Suppose you create your function:

```
def add(a, b): return a + b
```

If you write `add`, that's a function. But if you write `add(2,4)`, or `add(a, b)`  assuming that a and b are defined, then you are *calling* the function, so you get a result. These are two completely different things: there is `f`, a *callable*, and `f(a,b)` which returns a value.

So if you write:

```
>>> f = add
>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
```

That's what you want, you now have a function that does exactly what `add` does (and you could say it actually *is* add).

By contrast, if you write:

```
>>> f = add(a,b)
>>> type(f)
<class 'int'>
>>> f
11
```

That's a value.

So to make a long story short:

```
from operator import add, sub

def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    """
    Return a+abs(b), but without calling abs.

    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, 3)
    5
    >>> a_plus_abs_b(2, -3)
    5
    """
    if b < 0:
        f = sub
    else:
        f = add

    return f(a, b)
```